# In Android, how to shift a cropped Image? (advanced ImageView positioning)

Tags: android, imageview, crop

I am trying to show a specific part/frame of a bigger picture in an `ImageView`.
I tried out several different XML Attributes (`scaleType`, `maxHeight`, etc.) but I could not figure it out myself.

Basically what I want, is to show only this [top part](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ZuDv.png) of this [bigger picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6PsM4.png) which lies in my 'drawable' folder, at the top of my activity.

Code so far:

```
<ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
        android:src="@drawable/coffee"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
```

What can I do to get the wanted result, i.e. to shift the cropped image to show only the top part.

Comment: android:scaleType="fitStart" doesn't work?

Comment: sadly no, this is the result : http://i.imgur.com/8SrdDD2.png

Answer (score 0):

Try this one ,its working fine :

```
public class TopCropImageView extends ImageView {
    public TopCropImageView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
        super.onLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom);
        recomputeImgMatrix();
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean setFrame(int l, int t, int r, int b) {
        recomputeImgMatrix();
        return super.setFrame(l, t, r, b);
    }      

    private void recomputeImgMatrix() {
        final Matrix matrix = getImageMatrix();

        float scale;
        final int viewWidth = getWidth() - getPaddingLeft() - getPaddingRight();
        final int viewHeight = getHeight() - getPaddingTop() - getPaddingBottom();
        final int drawableWidth = getDrawable().getIntrinsicWidth();
        final int drawableHeight = getDrawable().getIntrinsicHeight();

        if (drawableWidth * viewHeight > drawableHeight * viewWidth) {
            scale = (float) viewHeight / (float) drawableHeight;
        } else {
            scale = (float) viewWidth / (float) drawableWidth;
        }

        matrix.setScale(scale, scale);
        setImageMatrix(matrix);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for a solution but I kind of was searching for a shorter XML solution, if it needs this much java code, it would be much simpler to just use a second already manually  cropped image as resource.